# How to retrieve "profile_" only filelds?

Tags: users

Now I load user profile fields of a `$uid`  by:

```
$thisuser = user_load(array('uid' => $uid));
profile_load_profile($thisuser);
drupal_json($thisuser);
```

Is there a quick way to filter only fields with leading `profile_` in `$thisuser` and so `drupal_json` displays only profile values?

Answer (score 1):

The condition should be `preg_match("/^profile_/", $profile)`. Have look at [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).